# Using Python to Compare Two Text Files Line by Line

Tags: python, count, line, frequency

I have two text files that I want to compare. First file contains unique items, and the second file contains same items but repeated numerous times. I want to see how many times each line is repeated in the second file. This is what I wrote:

```
import os
import sys

f1 = open('file1.txt')  # this has the 27 unique lines, 
f1data = f1.readlines()

f2 = open('file2.txt')  # this has lines repeated various times, with a total of 11162 lines
f2data = f2.readlines()

sys.stdout = open("linecount.txt", "w")


for line1 in f1data:
    linecount = 0
    for line2 in f2data:
        if line1 in line2:
        linecount+=1

    print line2, crime
```

The problem is, when I add up the line count result it returns 11586, instead of 11162. What is the reason for this increase in the line count?

Is there another way of getting a line frequency output using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#in:

> For the Unicode and string types, `x in y` is true if and only if *x* is a substring of *y*.

Instead of

```
    if line1 in line2:
```

I think you meant to write

```
    if line1 == line2:
```

---

Or maybe replace the whole

```
for line2 in f2data:
    if line1 in line2:
        linecount+=1
```

block by

```
if line1 in f2data:
    linecount += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not working even if we change the code a bit. I got some better results from this code.

```
>> import os
>> import sys

>> f1 = open('hmd4.csv')   
>> f2 = open('svm_words.txt')  

>> linecount = 0

>> for word1 in f1.read().split("."):
>>     for word2 in f2.read().split("\n"):
>>         if word1 in word2:
>>             linecount+=1 
>>             print (linecount)
```

Comment: still can not get why it compares only one value

Comment: how to get each word to compared with another word of two text files so that we can count the same strings